# lazy and greedy regular expressions

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression just to remove **HTML tags**  but unfortunately I remove the  **tag** and the content  of this tag, this is called **greedy regular expression**.

for example

if I have this tag

```
 <div> HELLO </div>
```

using my regular expression I remove the div tag (div) and I remove the content of this tag e.g (HELLO) word.

so please how to write a **lazy regular expression** just to remove the tag without removing the content of this tag.

Comment: Tags? You're going to need to give some more context. As it stands I have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: What language are you using? If you're using PHP, it already has a `strip_tags()` function, you don't need a regexp.

Comment: @BadWolf I added some explenation

Comment: @Mohammad you'll need to post your regex as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything, you should know that almost every script language has a `stip_tags` that do exactly what you want. But if you want a custom solution, a possible one could be this one:

```
<.*?>
```

to match a single tag. Following, signification of regex:

- < matches the characters < literally.
- . matches any character except newline.
- *? quantifier between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed. Lazy and not greedy. This means matches as few characters as possible.
- > matches the characters > literally.

Now the execution depends a little bit on the language script you are using.

---

for example, in php you would do something like:

```
$re = "/(<.*?>)/"; 
$str = "<p id=\"test\">This is a simple test</p>"; 

echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

check this link [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73ff570e1ab7b75b8435202dca276ccbb87a92e3) to see a working example.

---

And in javascript, you can do something like:

```
var re = "<.*?>";
var str = '<p id="test">This is a simple test</p>';

alert(str.replace(new RegExp(re,"gm"), ""));
```

Check this link [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/pq6x4bfn/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ungreedy regular expression, for instance :

```
< [^>]+>
```

`.+` will take every characters it can, meaning all.

Answer (score 1):

```
<[^>]*>
```

This should remove all the tags including the closing tags.